# Could not find the correct Provider<List<CurrentUser>> above this HomeBuilder Widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, chat, flutter-provider

I am trying to make chatting appp with fire base but stuck at getting list of recent chat  the error says =>  This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice

```
class ProviderInit extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return StreamProvider<User?>.value(
    value: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    initialData: null,
    child: const MaterialApp(
    title: 'Chat Application',
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home:   Recent(),
  ));
  }
}
class Recent extends StatefulWidget {
const Recent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
RecentState createState() => RecentState();
}

class RecentState extends State<Recent> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final User?  firebaseUser = Provider.of<User?>(context);
if ((firebaseUser != null)) {
        return ConversationProvider(user: firebaseUser);

  } else {
  return const LoginScreen();

   }
 }
 }


class ConversationProvider extends StatelessWidget {
 const ConversationProvider({

required this.user,
}) ;

final User user;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return StreamProvider<List<Convo>>.value(
    value: FireStoreMethods().streamConversations(user.uid),
   catchError: (_, __) => [],
    initialData: [],
    child:Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return ConversationDetailsProvider(user: user);
       }
     )

  );
}
}

class ConversationDetailsProvider extends StatelessWidget {
 const ConversationDetailsProvider({

required this.user,
 });

 final User user;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final List<Convo?> _convos = Provider.of<List<Convo>>(context);
     return StreamProvider<List<CurrentUser?>>.value(
           catchError: (_,err) => [],
            value: FireStoreMethods().getUsersByList(
                getUserIds(_convos)),
        initialData: [],
            child: Builder(
              builder: (context) {
                return  HomeBuilder();
              }
            ));


    }

 List<String> getUserIds(List<Convo?> _convos) {
  final List<String> users = <String>[];
 for (int i = 0; i < _convos.length; i++) {
  Convo c = _convos[i]!;
  c.userIds[0] != user.uid
      ? users.add(c.userIds[0])
      : users.add(c.userIds[1]);
   }
   return users;
 }
}


class HomeBuilder extends StatefulWidget {

@override
State<HomeBuilder> createState() => _HomeBuilderState();
 }

class _HomeBuilderState extends State<HomeBuilder> {

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final User? firebaseUser = Provider.of<User>(context);
 final List<Convo?> _convos = Provider.of<List<Convo>>(context);
 final List<CurrentUser?> _users = Provider.of<List<CurrentUser>>(context);
  return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            // IconButton(
            //     onPressed: Authentication.handleLogout,
            //     icon: Icon(Icons.first_page, size: 30)),
            Text(firebaseUser!.displayName!, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),

          ],
        )),
    body: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: getWidgets(context, firebaseUser, _convos, _users))
    );
     }

   // void createNewConvo(BuildContext context) {
     Map<String, CurrentUser> getUserMap(List<CurrentUser?> users) {
    final Map<String, CurrentUser> userMap = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    CurrentUser u = users[i]!;
    userMap[u.uid] = u;
    }
    return userMap;
    }

 List<Widget> getWidgets(
  BuildContext context, User user, List<Convo?> _convos, List<CurrentUser?> _users) {
 final List<Widget> list = <Widget>[];
 if (_convos != null && _users != null && user != null) {
  final Map<String, CurrentUser> userMap = getUserMap(_users);
  for (int i = 0; i < _convos.length; i++) {
    Convo c = _convos[i]!;
    if (c.userIds[0] == user.uid) {
      list.add(ConvoListItem(
          user: user,
          peer: userMap[c.userIds[1]]!,
          lastMessage: c.lastMessage));
    } else {
      list.add(ConvoListItem(
          user: user,
          peer: userMap[c.userIds[0]]!,
          lastMessage: c.lastMessage));
    }
  }
}

return list;
```

}
}

some one please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That is quite a long code but I get the gist of it since I encountered one like this earlier today.

It is quite simple to be honest, one of the most optimal and easiest solution is to always use the all of your providers as the parent of your MaterialApp widget (you can use MultiProvider class along with Consumer3(3 or whatever is the number of your providers you want to use, max upto 6).

To debug this yourself or how to find what was the problem, I highly recommend opening Dart dev tool on browser and checking out the widget hierarchy, and observe whether the place where you were trying to access the provider actually falls under the hierarchy or not? If it doesn't you need to figure out what you can do to make it happen which will eventually solve your problem.

But it is also recommended to use providers at the root of your application.